# get data from json web service every second

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I'd created a json web service for a windows phone project. I need to recuperate the data from the web service each seconds, i use a DispatcherTimer system with threads

```
private void client_DownloadInfoConf(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            //some code
            DispatcherTimer TradeThread = new DispatcherTimer();
            TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            TradeThread.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            TradeThread.Start();

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + e.Error);
    }
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client_quest = new WebClient();


        client_quest.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("url" + info_conf.id));
        client_quest.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadQuestConf); 
    }
    private void client_DownloadQuestConf(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            string text = e.Result;
            QuestConf resultat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestConf>(e.Result);
            string sub = texte.Substring(0, 5);
            TextBlock text_quest = new TextBlock();
            foreach (var cust in resultat)
            {

                //The problem is here, i can't retrieve data from the object
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Error);
    }
```

The probleme here is that if i try to get the data from the "var cust", an error occurs, i can't extract the data from the object...

The classes, made for extract the data of the json web service

```
 public class Question
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
    }

    public class QuestConf:List<object>
    {
        public Question question { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You should consider using websocket instead of polling every second, [signalr](http://signalr.net/) might be a good fit for your case

Comment: I polling every second for tests, the project will ask the webservice every 30 seconds

Comment: `foreach (var cust in resultat)` You forgot to put the part where you initialize the `resultat` variable

Comment: @KooKiz Oh sorry i cut parts of my code after submit it here, and i cut this initialisation, this variable is initialized as "QuestConf resultat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestConf>(e.Result);", i add this on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting your data from a web service and want to deserialize to the object, I believe you should add [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to your class and properties. Try like this for every object that you retrieve from web service:

```
[DataContract]
public class QuestConf:List<object>
{
    [DataMember]
    public Question question { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}
```